# Creating a migration for a model with multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a bit confused about how I would go about creating a migration for a model with multiple associations to the same table.

```
class Kill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player, :class_name => 'Player'
  belongs_to :killed, :class_name => 'Player'
end
```

and

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :kills, :class_name => 'Kill', :foreign_key => 'kills_id'
  has_many :killed_by, :class_name => 'Kill', :foreign_key => 'killed_by_id'
end
```

Is this setup right? I want to create a migration for this but I have been using

```
rails g migration Player kill:reference killed_by:reference
```

in the past for similar things, but it seems like since `kill` isn't a direct reference to the class name it does not work. How should I be creating the migration for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work

```
rails g migration add_kills_id_and_kill_by_id_to_players kills_id:integer kill_by_id:integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 rails g migration AddKillIdAndKillByIdToPlayers kill:references kill_by:references
```